# MSAL (Desktop & Mobile) not using proper redirect_uri

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

I have registered an App in Azure AD with the following manifest :

```
{
"id": "<ID>",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": null,
"appId": "<app id>",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-10-18T15:35:56Z",
"certification": null,
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [],
"informationalUrls": {
    "termsOfService": null,
    "support": null,
    "privacy": null,
    "marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "app-func-myapp-client",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
"oauth2Permissions": [],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
    "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
    "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [],
"publisherDomain": "mydomain.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
    {
        "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
        "type": "InstalledClient"
    }
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
        "resourceAppId": "<app id>",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "<id>",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
        "resourceAccess": [
            {
                "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                "type": "Scope"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
 }
```

I then tries to get an access token with MSAL from a .NET Desktop App

```
        var strApplicationID = "<my appid>";
        IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;

        PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(strApplicationID)
            .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .Build();

        string[] listScopes = new string[] {
            "profile",
            "email",
            "openid",
            $"api://{strApplicationID}/<somescope>"
        };

        var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        try
        {
            authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(listScopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(authResult.AccessToken);
```

Instead of popping the MSAL Authentication window, it starts a browser page. Once I login, I get the exception. "invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application."

[image]

In the URL, I clearly sees that it tries to use localhost in the redirect_uri, which doesn't make sense as I explicitly configured my App Reg for "Desktop and Mobile" Authentication.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

To work around the problem, follow these steps to update your app registration:

1. Go to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and login with the account you used in the quick-start download.
2. Locate the app by app ID and select it. You can get your app ID by opening the OAuth.resw file in Visual Studio.
3. When prompted to edit in the Azure Portal, choose "Not now".
4. Find the "Native Application" section, and choose "Add URI".
5. Enter "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".
6. Choose "Save" at the bottom of the page.